# Adding tab spaces in a file using ant

Tags: java, apache, ant

Can we add a tabular space in a file using `Ant` (for example using `echo` or something)?

I have a requirement where I need to have a tabular space between words and I need to create this file using `Ant`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this trick define a tab variable and use a html hex entity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="test" default="build" basedir=".">
<property name="tab" value="&#x0009;" />
<target name="build">
  <echo message="Run build task" />

  <echo message="file row 1${line.separator}" file="log.txt" append="false" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <echo message="file${tab}row${tab}2${line.separator}" file="log.txt" append="true" encoding="UTF-8" />
</target>

</project>
```